# How to web scrape for every item in every page using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to get every item in every page within the given url but it returns either nothing or just a few items. It's suppose to go through all the pages and get every item name price and link, but it seems it's only going through one page and just grabbing a couple of items.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

search_term = input("What product do you want to search for? ")

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)        Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Referer': 'https://www.example.com/',
}

url = f"https://www.newegg.ca/p/pl?d={search_term}&N=4131"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

page_text = doc.find(class_="list-tool-pagination-text").strong
pages = int(str(page_text).split("/")[-2].split(">")[-1][:-1])

items_found = {}

for page in range(1, pages + 1):
    url = f"https://www.newegg.ca/p/pl?d={search_term}&N=4131&page={page}"
    page = requests.get(url).text
    doc = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

    div = doc.find(class_="item-cells-wrap border-cells items-grid-view four-cells expulsion-one-cell")
    items = div.find_all(string=re.compile(search_term))

    for item in items:
        parent = item.parent
        if parent.name != "a":
            continue

        link = parent['href']
        next_parent = item.find_parent(class_="item-container")
        try:
            price = next_parent.find(class_="price-current").find("strong").string
            items_found[item] = {"price": int(price.replace(",", "")), "link": link}
        except:
            pass

sorted_items = sorted(items_found.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['price'])

for item in sorted_items:
    print(item[0])
    print(f"${item[1]['price']}")
    print(item[1]['link'])
    print("-------------------------------")
```

---

here are some outputs i get:

What product do you want to search for? 3080

Process finished with exit code 0 # with this i am getting nothing.

### What product do you want to search for? 3070
ZOTAC GAMING GeForce RTX 3070 AMP Holo LHR 8GB GDDR6 256-bit 14 Gbps PCIE 4.0 Gaming Graphics Card, HoloBlack, IceStorm 2.0 Advanced Cooling, SPECTRA 2.0 RGB Lighting, ZT-A30700F-10PLHR
$549
https://www.newegg.ca/zotac-geforce-rtx-3070-zt-a30700f-10plhr/p/1FT-000M-003A1?Item=1FT-000M-003A1

### GIGABYTE Eagle GeForce RTX 3070 8GB GDDR6 PCI Express 4.0 ATX Video Card GV-N3070EAGLE-8GD (rev. 2.0) (LHR)
$639
https://www.newegg.ca/gigabyte-geforce-rtx-3070-gv-n3070eagle-8gd/p/N82E16814932452?Item=N82E16814932452

### ZOTAC GAMING GeForce RTX 3070 Ti 8GB GDDR6X 256-bit 19 Gbps PCIE 4.0 Gaming Graphics Card, IceStorm 2.0 Advanced Cooling, SPECTRA 2.0 RGB Lighting, ZT-A30710Q-10P
$869
https://www.newegg.ca/zotac-geforce-rtx-3070-ti-zt-a30710q-10p/p/N82E16814500547?Item=N82E16814500547

### GIGABYTE Gaming OC GeForce RTX 3070 8GB GDDR6 PCI Express 4.0 ATX Video Card GV-N3070GAMING OC-8GD (rev. 2.0) (LHR)
$999
https://www.newegg.ca/gigabyte-geforce-rtx-3070-gv-n3070gaming-oc-8gd/p/N82E16814932449?Item=N82E16814932449

Process finished with exit code 0

i got a few but i expected way more as i can obviously see when i go to the website and search they have much more items.

Comment: Perhaps it's because you're using `requests` to fetch the page, which cannot process javascript.

Comment: Also I'd advise you to rename this variable, as you're overriding the existing loop variable with the same name: `page = requests.get(url).text`

Comment: I renamed the variable thanks, oversaw that one. As for request doesn't process JavaScript, it's the only thing I can think of as well, l I guess ill use Selenium instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example how to get info from all the pages:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.newegg.ca/p/pl"
params = {"d": "LG", "N": "4131", "page": 1}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0"
}

while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).content, "html.parser"
    )

    for item in soup.select(".item-cell"):
        title = item.select_one(".item-title")
        print(title.text)
        # ... get other info

    next_btn = soup.select_one('button[title="Next"]')

    if next_btn and "disabled" not in next_btn.attrs:
        params["page"] += 1
    else:
        break
```

Prints:

```
...

Refurbished LG Ultrawide 26WQ500-B 25.7" UW-UXGA LCD Monitor - 21:9 - 26" Class - In-plane Switching (IPS) Technology - LED Backlight - 2560 x 1080 - 16.7 Million Colors - FreeSync - 250 Nit - 5 ms - 75 Hz ...
Refurbished LG 27UP600 27" 4K (3840x2160) 5ms IPS FreeSync Monitor, White
Refurbished LG UltraGear 24GN60T-B 24 in. FHD IPS HDR Monitor with AMD FreeSync
Refurbished LG 27BK750Y-B, Black 27" 5ms (GTG) 1920 x 1080, FHD IPS Display, Height, Tilt, Swivel and Pivot Adjustable Built-in 1.2W 2ch Stereo Speakers
Open Box LG UltraFine 27UQ850-W 27" UHD 3840 x 2160 (4K) 60 Hz FreeSync (AMD Adaptive Sync) LCD / LED Monitors
Refurbished LG 34GN850-B.AUS 34-Inch Curved UltraGear Gaming Monitor - IPS - LED - 3440 x 1440 - 21:9 - 1000:1 - 1 ms - 400 cd/m2 - 160 Hz - G-Sync - FreeSync - Adaptive-Sync - Black
Refurbished LG 27QN880-B 27" QHD (2560x1440) 75Hz 5ms IPS FreeSync Monitor, Black
Open Box LG UltraGear 34" Quad HD 3440 x 1440 2K 160Hz (OC) 1ms 2xHDMI DisplayPort Radeon FreeSync 2 NVIDIA G-Sync Compatible USB 3.0 Hub Nano IPS Curved Gaming Monitor
```